# Return parent node after string search in XML - PHP

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, simplexml

I have an XML file like so:

```
<GenResponse>
  <Detail1></Detail1>
  <Detail2></Detail>
  <DataNodes>
    <DataNode>
      <NodeDetails1>
        <node4>Parrot Musky Truck Moo</node4>
        <node5>Tinker Singer Happy Fool</node5>
        <node6>
          <FurtherDetails>
            <Node>Musky</Node>
            <Node>Lorem Ipsum</Node>
          </FurtherDetails>
      </NodeDetails1>
      <NodeDetails2>ID</NodeDetails2>
    </DataNode>
    <DataNode>
      <NodeDetails1>
        <node4>Sky Star Panet Shoe</node4>
        <node5>Rusky Husky Musky Boo</node5>
      </NodeDetails1>
      <NodeDetails2>ID</NodeDetails2>
    </DataNode>
  </DataNodes>
</GenResponse>
```

I would like to know how I would inject a search string "Musky" to a PHP function and get back `<DataNode>...</DataNode>` & `<DataNode>...</DataNode>` back?

Essentially I would like to search a huge XML file for a string and return all the DataNode's which contain the string back.

If this is possible with SimpleXML it would be great. Else any other solution is also fine.

EDIT: Notice how "Musky" can be in different nodes under `<DataNode>`

Comment: if you haven't start coding yet, you can search thru nodes by way of xpath http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3

Comment: Are you  sure that your word will be always in node2

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Yes. The XML would contains 100s of such node2's and the search string would fall anywhere inside node2s. Thanks

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I am checking the answer.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('data/your_XML_File.xml'); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 
// seach records by tag value: 
// find nodes with  text
$res = $xml->xpath("node2[contains(., 'Musky')]"); 
print_r($res);
```

//For testing purpost just copy paste following code in editor , For testing , I didnt use separate xml file.

```
<?php
//$xmlStr = file_get_contents('test.xml'); 
$xmlStr = '<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4>Parrot Singer Truck Moo</node4>
      <node5>Tinker Musky Happy Fool</node5>
    </node3>
    <node7>ID</node7>
  </node2>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4>Sky Star Panet Shoe</node4>
      <node5>Rusky Husky Musky Boo</node5>
    </node3>
    <node7>ID</node7>
  </node2>
</node1>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 
// seach records by tag value: 
// find nodes with  text
$res = $xml->xpath("node2[contains(., 'Musky')]"); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res); 

?>
```

It gives proper output , i tried

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [node3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [node4] => Parrot Singer Truck Moo
                    [node5] => Tinker Musky Happy Fool
                )

            [node7] => ID
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [node3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [node4] => Sky Star Panet Shoe
                    [node5] => Rusky Husky Musky Boo
                )

            [node7] => ID
        )

)
```

Comment: This worked for the sample xml. But the xml I used returns lots of Errors, mostly this: 

`SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 12: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name`

I think this is because it has lots of " , ' , & characters in it. I tried using `addslashes()` but then this Error shows up:
`SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected`

Comment: Then you should tell me , and you should solve those errors ELSE write custom code which will be very complex to handle , manage ..and lots more :) Happy custom coding .

Comment: And let me tell you , we have Google . Didnt you take efforts to do simple Googling ? https://www.google.com/search?q=SimpleXMLElement%3A%3A__construct()%3A+Entity%3A+line+12%3A+parser+error&oq=SimpleXMLElement%3A%3A__construct()%3A+Entity%3A+line+12%3A+parser+error&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.554j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @SunilPachlandia I have refined the XML format. Although in <DataNode> there are more than 50 children, subchildren. I have also handled the & issue. Now the solution given by @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com should be modified at `$res = $xml->xpath("node2[contains(., 'Musky')]"); ` ? If yes then please help me how to search in DataNode. The hierarchical level of DataNode shown in the updated question is exactly where it is in the actual XML. PS: I'm new to this, so sorry if Im asking stupid questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and you can find your search word.I have made it a `function` just pass your keyword and you will get your result,

```
function findWord($findVar)
{
    $catalog = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile.xml");

    $category = $catalog->node2;

    $found = 0;
    foreach($category as $c)
    {
        foreach($c->node3 as $node3)
        {
            $node4 = (string) ($node3->node4);
            $node5 = (string) ($node3->node5);
            if (stripos(strtolower($node4),strtolower($findVar)))
            {
                echo 'Found!!'.'<br/>';
                $found++;
            }
            if (stripos(strtolower($node5),strtolower($findVar)))
            {
                echo 'Found!!'.'<br/>';
                $found++;
            }
        }

        if (stripos(strtolower((string)$c->node7),strtolower($findVar)))
        {
            echo 'Found!!'.'<br/>';
            $found++;
        }   
    }
    if ($found == 0)
    {
        echo "No result";
    }
}

$findVar = 'Musky';
findWord($findVar);
```

Comment: The function searches only in node4, node5 & node7? Meaning If there are more nodes inside node2, it wouldnt be searching them?

Comment: You have to create a variable for each of them.

Comment: Ok. But there are probably more that 50 nodes under node2 in that xml. So this wouldn't do good. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Wait let me find better solution

Comment: @eNeMetcH , didn't you check my solution ?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia , why are you doing custom coding if its already available using `xpath contains` ?

Comment: In `stripos(strtolower($node5)) ` ,If you use  `strtolower` then you dont need `stripos` , simple `strpos` will work

Comment: @eNeMetcH Is there any limit of child subchild hierarchy in your XML.